# Animate cell in gridview

Tags: android, animation, gridview, picasso

I have a gridview and I'm using Picasso library to populate it, I want to add an animation to each cell in the grid to slide in from the bottom, from what I've seen and read the only way to do this is through the Picasso library which it seems only supports .fade is this true, if so I need a new library and glide doesn't support it from what I've seen, is there another approach? Or does anyone know a library I can use that does support this kind of thing?

Comment: Well you can do something like this 1 set ImaeVisbility to be invisible 2 Load your Image from url into ImageView 3 (when image has loaded) set The Image Visbility on and start an animation by using Animation class provided by android

Comment: @L-X that's very helpful I asked this elsewhere and somebody told me something very similar, the images are loaded from drawables, but your point really i guess really is that it's not directly Picasso that would handle this, but it can tell me when to handle it myself, thank you, if you have some code to add before I do I'll mark yours as the correct answer

Comment: The problem with Picasso is they don't provide a function which tells you image has been loaded I have added code maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment you to do this with **Nostra’s Universal Image loader** as it comes with function like onLoadingStart() and onLoadingComplete() to set your code

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photoUrl, imageView,
            new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1,
                        Bitmap arg2) {
                    // Here The magic happens , make your ImageView visible and start animation
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.animation);
                    imageView.startAnimation(anim);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1,
                        FailReason arg2) {
                    // Here you can also specify a defferent image from drawable 

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

The animation is xml animation that has been specified in anim folder inside res folder

Comment: For more information about Universal Image Loader see [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-5-image-loading-library/)

Comment: Yeah I think your right thanks @L-X time to switch I think